# Will the Scenic Ribbon ever be supported by the MFC Feature Pack?

Tags: mfc, windows-7, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack

My team has spent a long time developing a nice UI using the ribbon included in the VS2008 MFC Feature Pack.

Now that Windows 7 is out and the look and feel of the ribbon has changed, my application looks out of date already, and it hasn't even been released yet :/

I want the look and feel of the Windows 7 ribbon ("scenic ribbon") ideally without changing anything - does anyone know whether there will be an update to the feature pack which will solve this?

I can't move to using the Windows 7 SDK ribbon, because I need to support XP, and the 7 SDK only supports 7 and Vista.

The only alternative I can think of is to go for a 3rd party library such as [BCGControlBar Pro](http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour256.htm) or [Prof-UIS Elegant Ribbon](http://www.prof-uis.com/elegant-ribbon/controls-framework-overview.aspx), both of which I don't mind paying for but it's the amount of rework that's the issue (presumably the BCG one would be the easiest to migrate to, as the MFC Feature Pack ribbon is based on that one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/10/01/ribbon-designer.aspx) shows that in VS2010 the MFC ribbon will have a "Windows 7" style.

So I guess I just need to wait for VS2010. Result!